# Learning efficient algorithms

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Up until now I've mostly concentrated on how to properly design code, make it as readable as possible and as maintainable as possible. So I alway chose to learn about the higher level details of programming, such as class interactions, API design, etc.

Algorithms I never really found particularly interesting. As a result, even though I can come up with a good design for my programs, and even if I can come up with a solution to a given problem it rarely is the most efficient.

Is there a particular way of thinking about problems that helps you come up with an as efficient solution as possible, or is it simple a matter of practice and/or memorizing?

Also, what online resources can you recommend that teach you various efficient algorithms for different problems?

Comment: Some more details: I'm not talking about design patterns, how to traverse a tree, and other common stuff. One example of what I'm looking for is this: You have a list of numbers and you know just one of them is unique (the others all appear exactly two times). You have to determine which is the unique number in O(n): you use the XOR operation.

Comment: that's a nice trick for solving Project Euler-style problems, but do you encounter that kind of problem in your day job?

Comment: @larsmans I realize it's not something you encounter in a real world scenario, but surely (in some different form) it has uses (right?). I'm consider myself to be able to write otherwise efficient programs when only logic is involved, but I'm not that good at efficiently solving these kind of abstract problems. (I'm in high school, I don't have a job. :) )

Comment: aha. Well, some of the more "exotic" algorithms do pop up now and then (pigeonhole sort, Boyer-Moore majority vote, string searching stuff), but I stick to my point that data structures are much more important. If any book or tutorial teaches you algorithms without data structures, it's probably not worth reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Data dominates**. If you design your program around the right abstract data structures (ADTs), you often get a clean design, the algorithms follow quite naturally and when performance is lacking, you should be able to "plug in" more efficient ones.

A strong background in maths and logic helps here, as it allows you to visualize your program at a high level as the interaction between functions, sets, graphs, sequences, etc. You then decide whether the sets need to be ordered (balanced BST, O(lg n) operations) or not (hash tables, O(1) operations), what operations need to supported on sequences (vector-like or list-like), etc.

If you want to learn some algorithms, get a good book such as Cormen et al. and try to implement the main data structures:

- binary search trees
- generic binary search trees (that work on more than just `int` or strings)
- hash tables
- priority queues/heaps
- dynamic arrays

Comment: I can't agree more. Clean coding helps abstracting away the real underlying algorithms (which are "implementation details"). Therefore, your reading of a good book (eg. Cormen) becomes orthogonal to writing code.

Answer (score 7):

[Introduction To Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) is a great book to get you thinking about efficiency of different algorithms/data structures.

The authors of the book also teach an algorithms course on MIT . You can find most lectures [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that in coming up with good algorithms (which is actually part of good design IMHO), you have to develop a way of thinking. This is best done by studying algorithm design. By study I don't mean just knowing all the common algorithms covered in a textbook, but actually understanding how and why they work, and being able to apply the basic idea contained in them to actual problems you are trying to solve.

I would suggest reading a good book on algorithms (my favourite is CLRS). For an online resource I would recommend the series of articles in the [TopCoder Algorithm Tutorials](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index).

I do not understand why you would mention practice and memorization in the same breath. Memorization won't help you at all (you probably already know this), but practice is essential. If you cannot apply what you learned, its not really learning. You can practice at various online programming contest/puzzle sites like [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl), [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) and [PythonChallenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com).

Comment: +1 for linking algorithm design and program design. It's all too easy to just take Knuth's "root of all evil" quote out of context; good programs and even good interfaces should be designed for both correctness and speed.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations:
First of all i recommend the book "Intro to Algorithms, Second Edition By corman", great book has most(if not all) of the algorithms you will need. (Some of the more important topics are sorting-algorithms, shortest paths, dynamic programing, many data structures like bst, hash maps, heaps).

another great way to learn algorithms is http://ace.delos.com/usacogate, great practice after the begining.

To your questions you will just get used to write good fast running code, after a little practice you just wouldnt want to write un-efficient code.

Comment: USACO is nice for learning how to solve the NP-complete problems in very little time, but it has little to do with the actual problems in software engineering.

Comment: That book is a lot more than just an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

While I think @larsmans is correct inasmuch that understanding logic and maths is a fast way to understanding how to choose useful ADTs for solving a given problem, studying existing solutions may be more instructive for those of us who struggle with those topics. In particular, reviewing code of established software (OSS) that solves some similar problem as the one you're interested in.

I find a particularly good method for this method of study is reviewing unit tests of such a project. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), for example, has a source control repository containing numerous examples. While it doesn't reveal the underlying algorithms, it helps trace to particular functionality that solves a certain problem. This leads to an opportunity for studying its innards - i.e. an interesting algorithm. In Lucene's case [inverted indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) come to mind.

While this does not guarantee the algorithm you discover is the best, it's likely one that's received a lot scrutiny and probably comes from project with an active mailing that may answer your questions. So it's a good resource for finding a solution that is probably better than what most of us would come up with on our own.