# Learning Algorithms

Tags: python, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning efficient algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282969/learning-efficient-algorithms)

I recently came across an problem that was solved by applying the correct algorithm: [Calculating plugin dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287160/calculating-plugin-dependencies)

While I was eventually able to understand the logic of the prescribed algorithm, it was not an easy task for me.  The only reason I was able to come up with code that worked was because of the logic example on the wikipedia page.

Being entirely self taught, without any CS or math background, I'd like to at least get some practical foundation to being able to apply algorithms to solve problems.

That said, are there any great books / resources (something akin to 'algorithms for dummies') that doesn't expect you have completed college Algebra 9 or Calculus 5 that can teach the basics?  I don't expect to ever be a wizard, just expand my problem solving tool-set a little bit.

Doing an amazon search turns up a bunch of books, but I'm hoping you guys can point me to the truly useful resources.

The only language I have any real experience with is Python (a tiny bit of C) so whatever I find needs to be language agnostic or centred around Python/C.

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that say _this profile picture is offensive_?

Comment: I'm sort of in the same boat, being self taught. +1 I have done this same amazon search, and have been wondering where a good place to start would be.

Comment: @Burn, looks like tMC is just really looking forward to that hamburger.

Comment: I have the same feeling as Mr.Burn!

Comment: dont hate me because im beautiful :(

Comment: Learning algorithms is good, but be also aware that most of the time you will want to pick the right module for a job, one that already implements those. E.g. for your topological sort you could have used the excellent python-graph module. Having said that, you might find "Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures Using Python" by Miller & Ranum interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth is a Very Useful Book.

Comment: And a very tough one if the majority of reviewers that comment on difficulty are to be believed.

Comment: Yeah I just got the bookset for myself and its a tough cookie to tackle.

Comment: Is that something someone with no training in math or programming can make use of?

Comment: @tMC I think any algorithm book would be  tough for anybody who doesn't have an Algorithms course background and Knuth's would be the toughest.If there is anything that would easily teach anybody algorithms is that `trying` to write small programs after a long `thinking of how to write it with examples`. Check [Algorithms are everywhere!](http://personal.denison.edu/~havill/algorithmics/algs.html).Good luck.

Comment: @burn I figured as much.  I guess i'm trying to figure out how to teach myself the content taught in basic algorithms courses.  I'm willing to work at it, i just have to start easy and work my way up :)

Comment: "Art of Computer Programming" is not one book - it's about **4 tomes** of books that go under that title. - Not recommendable as entry literature IMO.

Comment: @tMC Well, first thing to to be succesful is to be willing to learn it, I am sure you will handle that well.Try solving small problems in an algorithmic way.And never forget the rule "_divide and conquer_"

Answer (score 3):

A great book is "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein.

Probably not the easiest one but it is very good indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I found useful for myself the following sources:

- ["Analysis of Algorithms : An Active Learning Approach"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763707821) by Jeffrey J. McConnell;
- ["Python Algorithms: Mastering Basic Algorithms in the Python Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232374)(Expert's Voice in Open Source) by Magnus Lie Hetland. - this books seems to me to be a very like a previous book but from python developer point of view;
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs

Answer (score 1):

Steve Skiena's [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) is very good. It doesn't assume very much background knowledge, and covers several important topics in algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I found [Algorithms and Complexity](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AlgComp3.html) to be super helpful. I'm also without CS degree or anything.